# Connecting to Rackspace Cloud using ASP.net

Tags: rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I am trying to connect to Rackspace Cloud using Asp.net.

I've downloaded Rackspace.CloudFiles assembly from NuGet, and i am trying to connect to the server:

```
UserCredentials userCred = new UserCredentials("username", "api_key");
Connection connection = new Connection(userCred);
var containers = connection.GetContainers();
```

This works, but it connects every time to only one storage location. In rackspace control panel, i have more locations where i have containers.

Is there a way to specify the Location when i connect to Rackspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to get the entire OpenStack .NET SDK via NuGet; it allows you to connect to "the cloud" and then select containers based on region (or all regions, or course).

Such as this:

```
// Get a list of containers
CloudFilesProvider cfp = new CloudFilesProvider(_cloudIdentity);
IEnumerable<ContainerCDN> listOfContainers = cfp.ListCDNContainers(region: "DFW");
```

If you **do** decide to use the OpenStack .NET SDK, please don't hesitate to ask questions; I'm here to help.

-- Don Schenck, OpenStack .NET Developer Advocate, Rackspace

Comment: After lots of research i finally found OpenStack SDK and i am working with it right now, and everything works fine. If i will have any other questions, i will let you know, thank you:)

Comment: Hi, can you please help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254455/openstack-rackspace-cloud-files-net-sdk) question? Thanks