# OpenStack Rackspace Cloud Files .net SDK

Tags: openstack, rackspace-cloud, rackspace, cloudfiles, openstacknetsdk

I am trying to save an XML file to a non CDN Container from Sydney:

```
public void Save(XDocument document)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        document.Save(ms);
        ms.Position = 0;

        RackspaceCloudIdentity identity = new RackspaceCloudIdentity { Username = "username", APIKey = "xxxxxxxxxxx", CloudInstance = CloudInstance.Default };
        CloudFilesProvider provider = new CloudFilesProvider(identity);

        provider.CreateObject("XMLFiles", ms, "xmlFile1.xml", region: "syd");
    }
}
```

For a 1MB file, it takes about 50 seconds to upload (very long).

And, trying to download the file back, returns an empty result:

```
public void Read()
{
    RackspaceCloudIdentity identity = new RackspaceCloudIdentity { Username = "username", APIKey = "xxxxxxxxxxx", CloudInstance = CloudInstance.Default };
    CloudFilesProvider provider = new CloudFilesProvider(identity);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        provider.GetObject("XMLFiles", "xmlFile1.xml", ms, region: "syd");

        // ms.Length is 0
    }
}
```

I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh. I introduced this bug in commit [`799f37c`](https://github.com/openstacknetsdk/openstack.net/commit/799f37cb7ae4281a787a8f459dd4ef866e72881a) (first released in v1.1.3.0). I'm looking into the best workaround right now.

**Edit:** There is no workaround, but I filed [issue #116](https://github.com/openstacknetsdk/openstack.net/issues/116) for the issue, and after the [pull request](https://github.com/openstacknetsdk/openstack.net/pull/117) for it is merged, we'll release version 1.1.3.1 of the library to correct the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to access your control panel at mycloud.rackspace.com?

I used my control panel to upload an XML file, then used your code, above, to download the XML file. It worked fine.

I'm going now use the upload code you posted.

Just wanted you to know I'm looking into this.

Comment: Oh. So MINE works because I'm using a slightly older (pre-799f37c) build (see the comment by 280Z28, below).